# Using different DNS hosting providers for good redundancy?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Can I use three different free DNS hosting providers as namesevers for the same domain?

I can't pay for DNS hosting and so after some research I've found three different free DNS providers. None of them have a perfect uptime record though (understandably) and reliability is important to me. I wondered if I could set three different namerservers for my domain name (one from each provider). This way I'm covered when one or two of their free services goes down, right?

Apart from the time spent manually setting up the DNS three times (which isn't a problem as I only set up one or two domains a month) are there any downsides to this plan? Will this work? Is it a good idea?

Comment: Why not just pay the tiny amount something like Amazon's Route53 charges and avoid the trouble? Surely your time's worth the $6/year.

Comment: Not had any experience with Route53. Will have to investigate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work and yes offer redundancy. As you've mentioned in your question the major downside will be the manual management of all the records.

You may also find that some DNS providers only allow you to host your zone if all the NS records for the zone point to them, not allow you to edit some information such as TTLs leaving you out-of-sync.

But in theory, vendor-specific limits and time apart, I can see no reason why you can't multi-locate your DNS.

Comment: "Some DNS providers only allow you to host your zone if all the NS records for the zone point to them" like instances where they will only let me use their DNS if it's pointing to a hosting product I've bought from them?

Comment: Yes or they will check that your registered nameservers for the domain are set to them, and only them, before serving your zone. It's not all by any measure.